# Why using '-mfpu=neon' on XCODE4 causes errors?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, neon

I recently tries to use NEON for my applications. Many posts and Q&A tells that I have to specify "-mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp" to use NEON on iphone.

However, when I added this options to 'Other C Flags' section in XCODE 4, there were build error like this:

{standard input}:1270:selected FPU does not support instruction -- `vmov.f32 s0,#2.000000e+00'

I also tried to turn on / off 'Compile for Thumb', but there were no differences.

Why this error happens ??  and How could I enable NEON features on XCODE 4 ??

Answer (score 1):

NEON support is enabled by default when building for ARMv7.  You shouldn't need to do anything.  Did you try it before you started tinkering with the flags?